# Measuring probability that 2 sample originate from the same population

Tags: probability

I have two dataset that i want to compare.
each dataset contain the weight of 10 different person measured for 3 different day.

I am interested  in measuring the probabily that the two sample originate from the same population.

People seem to suggest doing a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test but i need a measurement.

I was thinking doing the EMD to compare the distribution for each day

EMD(dataset1-day1,dataset2-day1) + EMD(dataset1-day2,dataset2-day2) + EMD(dataset1-day3,dataset2-day3) 
But i could probably take each person as a 3d datapoint and do the EMD in 3d.

One other possibility was to do the Hausdorff distance but doing the average of the distance for each point instead of taking the maximum distance.

What are the main difference between the two technique.